# Changing VC issue in Swift. How to pass data between views in tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have four ViewController, I don't use an UITabbedbar because It's more difficult to customize.
I use modal segue but I think the memory consumption is excessive.
this is a screen shot of my first and second VC.
What I have to use to change View correctly?

[image]

---

That's the code I use :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "second") {
        let secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController;


    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with that code? (As of now it's not actually doing anything...)

Comment: I've called the segue "second"

Comment: You're not calling a segue in that code... You're simply reacting to the segue that's about to happen by setting secondVC to a local constant and doing nothing with it. If you remove that whole method, you'll see the segue is still performed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From your Storyboard diagram, it is clear that you have created a segue from each button in your "tab bar" to another view controller.  Except for the *unwind segue*, segues always create a new instance of the view controller they are switching to.  So if you use your setup to switch from view controller 1 to view controller 2 and then back to view controller 1, you won't be returning to the view controller you came from but instead you will be creating an entirely new view controller 1.

This is why your memory consumption is excessive.  You keep creating view controllers until your app crashes.

I would recommend you return to using a tab bar controller.  They were designed to allocate the view controllers once up front and then just switch between them.  Also, they have a standard look for a reason, it helps the user of your app know immediately how to interact with them.

---

To pass data between tabs, you won't use segues because there is no segue happening when you switch tabs.  There are many ways you can do this, but they all boil down to having model data stored where all of the tabs can access it.  This can be done with *CoreData* in a larger app.  For a simple app, you can do the following:

1. Create a custom subclass of `UITabBarController`.  Let's call it `CustomTabBarController`.  Have that class create and hold the model data that will be accessed by each of your tabs.

   **CustomTabBarController.swift:**

   ```
   import UIKit

   // This class holds the data for my model.
   class ModelData {
       var name = "Fred"
       var age = 50
   }

   class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

       // Instantiate the one copy of the model data that will be accessed
       // by all of the tabs.
       var model = ModelData()

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your Storyboard, in the Identity Inspector, change the class of `UITabBarController` to `CustomTabBarController`.

   [image]
3. In `viewWillAppear` in each of your tabs, get a reference to the model data and then you can use it.

   **FirstViewController.swift:**

   ```
   import UIKit

   class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

       override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
           super.viewWillAppear(animated)

           // Get a reference to the model data from the custom tab bar controller.
           let model = (self.tabBarController as! CustomTabBarController).model

           // Show that we can access and update the model data from the first tab.
           // Let's just increase the age each time this tab appears and assign
           // a random name.
           model.age += 1

           let names = ["Larry", "Curly", "Moe"]
           model.name = names[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(names.count)))]
       }

   }
   ```

   **SecondViewController.swift:**

   ```
   import UIKit

   class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
       @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
       @IBOutlet weak var ageLabel: UILabel!

       override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
           super.viewWillAppear(animated)

           // Get a reference to the model data from the custom tab bar controller.
           let model = (self.tabBarController as! CustomTabBarController).model

           // This tab will simply access the data and display it when the view
           // appears.
           nameLabel.text = model.name
           ageLabel.text = "\(model.age)"
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I think your answer's basically right on, but the OP's updated her answer to clarify that she's not using a tab bar. Perhaps you should edit your answer too to explain how your reasoning still applies.

Comment: How I can pass data between View with tab bar ?

Comment: @Mala, that line is just choosing a random name from the list of names and assigning it to the model.name.  It was just a demonstration to make the example do something interesting.

Comment: How can I use the model somewhere else that is not `viewWillAppear`  ?
What I mean is, how to make it available throughout the same viewController? So it can be used in different functions and so on

Comment: Any method in your viewController should be able to get a pointer to the model in the same way viewWillAppear does. That method is convenient because it runs each time the tab is selected.