# Setting a delegate when a specific tab is pressed

Tags: swift, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I have a delegate that I call logoSelectionDelegate. The delegate has one function to indicate if the user has changed their logo.

```
func userDidChangeLogo(image1: UIImage) {
    pickedImage = image1
}
```

I used to set the delegate using the prepareForSegue function as below:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SettingsIdentifier" {
        let viewController:SelectALogoViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SelectALogoViewController
        viewController.delegate=self

        if pickedImage != nil {

            viewController.pickedImage = pickedImage
        }



    }
}
```

This worked fine, however, now I have changed to a Tabbed application and I want to set the logoSelectionDelegate when the "settings" tab is pressed. Now I'm unsure how to do this, I was setting my TabBarController to be the logoSelectionDelegate, implementing my delegate function in the TabBarController.swift file and then using the didSelectViewController method to try and set the logoSelectionDelegate as below:

```
 func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1) {

        let viewController:SelectALogoViewController! = viewController as? SelectALogoViewController
        viewController.delegate=self

        if pickedImage != nil {

            viewController.pickedImage = pickedImage
        }

        println("Yes")
    }



    return true



}
```

I can't get this to work and would welcome your comments / answers

Comment: Who do you want the logoSelectionDelegate to be, the TabBarController or the UIViewController of the settings tab?

Comment: Hi Vacawama, I've simply just changed my design to save the logo using NSUserDefaults. Delegation between TabBarControllers seems a tricky subject as there is no "segue" between controllers that you get with UINavigationControllers.

Comment: NSUserDefaults is for storing preferences, not for passing data. It works, but it isn't the intended purpose. My answer here provides a way to pass and share data between tabs. Take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27619420/1630618

Comment: Thanks for a very comprehensive answer. This is part of my app that I haven't look at for a while and I can't remember why I was passing the logo back to my first viewcontroller, basically I just want the user to be able to select a logo and store his logo file location in the app for further use. I just figured it would be easier to do this with NSUserDefaults. I'm using a Realm database within my app. I'm not sure what the best design pattern is, to use the database or NSUserDefaults.

Comment: In your case, it is a preference ("my preference is to use the following logo"), so NSUserDefaults is entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the tab bar's view controllers with this:

```
let viewController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? SelectALogoViewController
    viewController?.delegate = self
```

Or the other option would be to call your methods directly and remove the delegate/protocol syntax altogether:

```
let viewController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? SelectALogoViewController
    viewController?.doSomething()
```