# How to Pass data between tabBarControllers

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am currently trying to pass data between two `UINavigationControllers` with a `UITableViewController` attached to each. I am navigating between these two controllers via a `UITabBarController`. I have been trying to use vacawama's solution on [Changing VC issue in Swift. How to pass data between views in tab bar controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618737/changing-vc-issue-in-swift-how-to-pass-data-between-views-in-tab-bar-controller) I am using the following code.

```
import UIKit

class placeData: Equatable {
var description : String
var selected : Bool

init (description : String, selected : Bool) {
    self.description = description
    self.selected = selected
}

}

class PlacesTabBarController: UITabBarController {

var placeDataArray = [placeData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

This is in the tabBarController custom class. In the other two controllers I declare the array I want to be pass between the view controllers and use the method in the link to populate the `UITableViewController`

```
var placeDataArray = [placeData]()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    placeDataArray = (self.tabBarController as PlacesTabBarController).placeDataArray
}
```

When the controllers load, however, the arrays are empty. In the example in the link, all the rest of the code is within the `viewWillAppear` function, where I need my array to be available to all of the corresponding `tableView` functions. I am not sure if I am just equating the arrays to zero on load. But my thought was that they would repopulate. Not sure what the correct way to go about this is. Any help would be great.

EDIT: My current structure is as follows:

```
 UITabBarController
  |              |
UINavigation  UINavigation
Controller     Controller
  |              |
UITableView      UITableView
Controller       Controller
```

The array is populated when the first tab loads. What I am trying to do is have the populated array in the second view controller, and if I edit it in the second view controller, I want the edits to stay in the first. So I want it to be passed by reference.

Comment: At what time "placeDataArray" will be filled with data in your PlacesTabBarController?

Comment: Do you mean two `UIViewControllers`? not two `UINavigationControllers`?

Comment: two `UINavigationControllers` I deleted the `UIViewControllers` and linked the two navigation controllers with the attached `UITableViewControllers`. The `placeDataArray` is populated when tab 1 loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would subclass the `UITabBarController` and make it a delegate for the two `UITableViewControllers`.

### CustomTabBarController

```
protocol CustomTabBarDelegate {
    var places:Array<placeData> { get set }
}

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, CustomTabBarDelegate {
    var places = Array<placeData>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        places = [PlaceData(),PlaceData()]

        var table1 = CustomTableViewController()
        var table2 = CustomTableViewController()

        table1.delegate = self
        table2.delegate = self

        var navController1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: table1)
        var navController2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: table2)

        self.viewControllers = [navController1, navController2]

    }
}
```

Then your `TableViewControllers` simply access the delegates array like so.

### CustomTableViewController

```
class CustomTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var delegate:CustomTabBarDelegate!

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return delegate.places.count
    }

}
```

Any changes to the array will be visible in each table after you `.reloadData()` - I have set the `CustomTableViewController` in my example to reload data every time the view appears, so when you change tabs they should refresh to show the latest changes.

---

*It's worth mentioning that in time it would probably be cleaner to have a separate class that manages your data instead of holding the array in the TabBarController.*

Comment: I deleted both of the `UIViewControllers` and added two `UINavigationControllers` and following them are the `UITableViewControllers`. I then linked the navigation controllers to the `tabBarController`. It is also worth mentioning that I want the data to be passed by reference not by value.

Comment: Ok and your TableViewControllers are inside your NavigationControllers?

Comment: Yes they are. See updated question above, hopefully that should provide the information you need.

Comment: Thats great thanks, to be clear you want the changes made in table2 to also be visible when you return to table1?

Comment: Correct, The array data will load in table1 where I can make changes to it, and then when I switch to table2, the array data comes over where I have a different set of options to alter the data in the array. Then when I switch back to table1, I would like those changes to the array to show in table1. So the array is going to be passed by reference.

Comment: Just to be clear, the variables to load before I present the `CustomTabBarController`, where would I put them to load before the `CustomTabBarController`

Comment: Just populate the array on the `tabController` instance before you present it, I have updated my answer to include this.

Comment: Sorry i'm fairly new to swift and i'm getting an error. I put the code determining what the delegate is for the two controllers in the view did load function  in the `CustomTabBarController` because I was getting errors by putting it outside of that function. Is this the correct place to put that code?

Comment: And i'm assuming I can populate the places array controller by putting it in the `viewDidLoad` function in the `CustomTabBarController`?

Comment: Yes you can, I have changed my answer to work as you are suggesting.

Comment: Terrific! it worked when I did it in a standalone project. However, my `tableView` outlet that is attached to the table is no longer working. This was used for the `dequeueReusableIdentifier` to populate the cell with values. Can't find anywhere on google where this issue has come up.

Comment: the error is "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" for every thing referencing the outlet by the way e.g var `cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell`. The error results for `tableView`

Comment: I think that is slightly outside the scope of your question, you should consider accepting this as an answer to your first issue and researching your new issue. If you need to ask a new question after research then do, but new questions should not be continued like this in a comment thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the app delegate..
Set a property there and call it from anywhere in your application.

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
var yourNeededData = appDel.yourPassingAroundDataProperty
```

Comment: I would use NSNotificationCenter instead of sharing using AppDelegate. IMO its more elegant. Or even using NSUserDefaults.

Comment: You can chose `NSUserDefaults` to save data and use it.

Comment: using NSNotificationCenter is bad performance-wise, you have to allocate listeners that might not be used.

Comment: NSUserDefaults should only be used to interact with the defaults system, to match a user's preferences..   https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html