# Pass data between views in TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitabbarcontroller

I have two views in a tab bar controller. View one has a label, and view two has a button and a textfield.

I want to allow the user to type something into the text field and press the button so that the text in the label in view one changes when they switch back to it.

I tried storing the contents of the text field in my tab bar controllers class, however I don't know how to get view one's label to update once I switch to it.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you need to add navigation controller each tab view controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Pass data between tabBarControllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664534/how-to-pass-data-between-tabbarcontrollers)

Comment: Have the second view read the data in `viewWillAppear`. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27619420/1630618.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to sort out this issue:

1. Create a singleton class, and add a property in that class. Change it values when updating from text field, and display it's value in label from other screen.
2. Use NSUserDefaults, it is also a singleton one, and will work as above. Just you need to call [[NSUserDefaults defaults] synchronize]; if you want to persist those values, after the app get exit.