# How can I segue to the second tab of a tab bar controller from the first tab?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have no problem actually performing the segue, but when I do, my tab bar disappears from the bottom of the view. I have made a storyboard segue from TabBarController1 to TabBarController2.

I've found a lot of answers for Objective-C, but none for Swift.

This is the code for performing the segue:

```
if requestsArray.count == 0 {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("offerSegue", sender: self)
            } else {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("confirm1", sender: self)
            }
```

Comment: What kind of segue are you using? The code you've posted doesn't seem particularly relevant.

Comment: It is wrong to use segues to switch between view controllers in a tab bar controller.  Segues create a new instance of a view controller, and you just want to switch.  See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27619420/1630618

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't want to segue. A segue creates a new instance of the destination view controller and presents it.

That's why your tab bar is disappearing. You are covering your tab bar controller, with it's 2 tabs, with a new instance of your TabBarController2.

You want to **switch** to the other tab.

What you want to do is to ask your owning tab bar controller to switch tabs.

`UIViewController` has a property tabBarController that lets you get to your owning tab bar controller.

TabBarControllers have a property `selectedIndex`  that let you select one of a tab bar controller's view controllers to become the active view controller.

So, send a message to your tab bar controller asking it to switch to the other tab.

### EDIT:

Other people aside from the OP have asked for sample code illustrating how to do this. I decided to create a sample project illustrating how to do it.

You can download it from Github: https://github.com/DuncanMC/TabBarControllers.git

I created a base class of UIViewController `ATabController` for the view controllers that are managed by the tab bar controller. The `ATabController.swift` file includes an enum to indicate which tab you want to select:

```
@objc enum Tab: Int {
  case first = 0
  case second
  case third
}
```

(Note that the enum has to be an Objective-C enum if you're going to pass parameters of type `Tab` to IBActions, since IBAction methods need to use Objective-C types and function signatures.)

It also includes a protocol `TabController`:

```
@objc protocol TabController {
  @objc func switchTab(to: Tab)
}
```

It also defines a delegate `tabDelegate`:

```
weak var tabDelegate: TabController?
```

The tab bar controller has a prepareForSegue (`prepare(for:sender:)`) that it uses to make itself the `tabDelegate` of all the view controllers it manages as tabs:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if let child = segue.destination as? ATabController {
    child.tabDelegate = self
  }
```

And then it implements the `switchTab(to:)` method:

```
@objc func switchTab(to: Tab) {
  let index = to.rawValue
  guard let viewControllerCount = viewControllers?.count,
    index >= 0 && index < viewControllerCount  else { return }
  selectedIndex = index
}
```

In any of the child view controllers that are tabs of the tab bar controller, you can use `IBAction` code like this to switch tabs:

```
@IBAction func handleFirstButton(_ sender: Any) {
  tabDelegate?.switchTab(to: .first)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this Duncan?...i.e. provide some sample code? I'm facing the same issue. I have a UITableViewCell in one tab that, upon selection, I'd like to segue to a different tab without having the bottom tab bar disappear. I discovered this after I post my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401083/how-can-i-perform-a-segue-to-a-different-tab-in-a-uitabbarcontroller-when-user-s maybe you can provide sample code there? Thanks

Comment: @Pangu, I don't have any sample code to give you. I haven't actually had to do this before, but the docs make it pretty clear how to make it work.

Comment: When you say "segue to a different tab" you are thinking wrong. A tab bar controller manages a set of persistent view controllers and switches between them. A segue always creates a brand new view controller. The two things are not equivalent. You do **NOT** segue to a different tab in a tab bart controller.

Comment: @Pangu, I edited my answer to include a link to a sample project, along with the relevant code. Understand that you do not **SEGUE** to the tabs of a tab bar controller. A segue always creates a new instance of a view controller. A tab bar controller, on the other hand, manages a set of view controllers that stick around for the life of your app, and it allows the user to switch freely between those tabs.

Answer (score 18):

If you're looking for how to change from one tab to another in a tab controller without using the tab bar you can do this

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = [number of tab]
```

Comment: how to go to outside tab bar controller to second bar item?

Comment: @user4410354, for example: let webView = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController?.childViewControllers[1].view.viewWithTag(501) as? WKWebView