# How to perform segue between UITabBars?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i have my application with 2 UITabBars - on the first mapview, on the second tableview. So what i want is to perform segue by tapping on the tableview cell and go to map(with some data). My problem is to make some realisation for automatic switching(or at least manual) between selected indexes tabbars. 
[image]

Now if tap on the cell i will have TWO tabbars with TWO maps

Answer (score 1):

I think you're reinstantiating the whole view by performing a segue. Look at this other issue: [How can I segue to the second tab of a tab bar controller from the first tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30971114/how-can-i-segue-to-the-second-tab-of-a-tab-bar-controller-from-the-first-tab) You probably can fix the issue by performing a standard selector that changes the `selectedViewController` property of the tabBar (probably passing more info), instead of a segue.