# Sending data between tab bars

Tags: ios, swift, tabs

i need to send a piece of data indicating which row sent it from one of my tab tableviewcontroller to main view controller, then I can take action based on the value in viewDidAppear

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //selectedRow = indexPath.row
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

and then do something in the other view controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //selectedRow = row sent from tab bar,
    //load data from plist at index of the selected row
}
```

Whats the best way to do this? Thanks

Comment: create singleton class with properties and just `set` it when you are switching to different tab bar controller i mean `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `get` when `viewDidAppear` of your another `VC` is getting call.

Comment: see this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27619420/1630618

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare property for your other view controller and set its value in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

OtherViewController:

```
class OtherViewController: UIViewController {
    var selectedRow: Int = 0

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // load data from plist at index using selectedRow property
    }
}
```

`TableViewController`'s `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var tabIndex = 0

    if let vc = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[tabIndex] as? OtherViewController {
        vc.selectedRow = indexPath.row
    }
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = tabIndex
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used vc =  self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0].childViewControllers[0] as! TableViewController? to select my destination view controller

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepareForSegue and then you will be able to transfer information between the segues.
Take a look at the identifier property and the destination one

Comment: Thanks but there is no segue / segue identifier as i'm switching between tabbed views?

Comment: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(nullable id)sender is an UIViewController methods