# How to pass data between two view controllers of a TabBarContoller where the first view controller is a TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I am pretty new to iOS application programming in SWIFT. As part of our course, we are building an app which has a TabBarController as the root. The first view controller of the TabBarController is a TableView Controller and a second view controller is a MapViewController. What I want to achieve is to select a row in the TableView which would plot related values in the MapView. Also the map should also be accessible through the tab bar (if the map tab is chosen the previously plotted values will be shown).

Initially I tried to do this using segue. When a cell is selected the segue is called and when the tab is selected it doesn't. But with this method the segue is making a new instance of the MapViewController rather than calling the actual one. So, I removed the segue and tried to pass through custom class as advised in many posts here. But the problem is since the map is loaded in viewWillAppear, the values are not getting properly updated. I would like advice on how to achieve this. When a user selects the cell in the table view the actual MapViewController should be opened with data properly updated.

Thank You

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27619420/1630618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to pass data between two viewcontrollers is to get reference of viewcontroller where you want to pass data.

Suppose in **ViewController1** user select some tableview cell then in method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if let secondVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? ViewController2 {
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
        secondVC.instanceVariable = "updated value"
    }
}
```

This will take to viewController2 and update the instance variable value.Now in `viewWillAppear` method you can reload mapview.

Comment: Hi, Thank You for the advice, it worked! Actually I did a similar thing before too, so when I tried your method i got the same result. I realised that my object is being updated without any issues. Rather the issue is with map annotation. Since the map is being called in viewWillAppear method, the annotations are not automatically updated.. The first click on the annotation shows me the old value, and the second click shows the new value - in fact they are alternating like that.

Comment: Hey I got it. Actually the values were being appended instead of updated. So corrected that also, used the viewdidAppear method to delete annotations overtime view is disappeared. Finally got what I needed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you'll have to use Delegate-Protocol methods to pass data.

1. Declare a protocol in your tableviewcontroller

   `protocol refreshMapProtocol
   {
       func refresh(data: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
   }`
2. Declare a delegate property on your tableviewcontroller

   `var delegate: refreshMapProtocol?`
3. Conform to this protocol in your mapViewController
4. On didSelectRowAtIndexPath of your tableviewcontroller, call the delegate method

   `delegate?.refresh()
   tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 1`
5. Finally in your mapViewController declare this `refresh` method to reload the map data.