# Using data in another tab of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an app have three tabs `UITabBarController`. In the second tab's `UIViewController` I have some variables I want to use them with their values in first tab. What should I do?

Comment: You can save them in NSUSerDefaults, and retrieve them on didappear of the next VC

Comment: Take a look at this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27619420/1630618

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each tab and its controller stack in a `UITabBarController`should be independent.

If you are passing some settings value I would recommend you to use a `NSUSerDefault` to store and retrieve the user settings.

The others way is either set up a `protocol` or use a `Observer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below line of code

```
class superTabVC : UITabBarController
{
   var a
}

 class tab1 :  superTabVC
{

 }

class tab2 :  superTabVC
{
}
```

this way you can use var `a` in both tab.