# How to use share data between view controlles

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, pass-data

i want to use a data between views but i have a tab bar view control. Actually my initial view login view i get "access_token" as a sting and if i can successfully login pass tab bar control's first view but i want to use access token string in second tab bar view for get another data from webservice. how can i get acces token string in tab bar controller's second view?

```
self.strSuccessful = json["acces_token"] as? String
```

my second view in tab bar view controller

```
class SalesVC: UIViewController {
   var strAccesToken: String!
  }
```

my initial (first view controller not inculude tabbar because login screen)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let salesViewController = segue.destination as! SalesVC

    salesViewController.strAccessToken = strSuccessfulAccesToken


}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27619420/1630618

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is you can use `UserDefaults` and store your access token in it in `LoginController` after that in `SecondTabController` retrieve access token from user defaults.

Save access token in `UserDefaults`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(strSuccessfulAccesToken, forKey: "AccessToken")
```

Now in `SecondTabController` retrieve access token from user defaults.

```
if let accessToken =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "AccessToken") {
    print(accessToken)
}
```

If you want to manually passed the access token from `LoginController` then set access token in `prepareForSegue` of `LoginController` like this way.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let tabbar = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
    if let salesVC = tabbar.viewControllers[1] as? SalesVC {
        salesVC.strAccessToken = strSuccessfulAccesToken
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general case you can use `UserDefaults` to store simple data (like UI preference, for example), but you have mentioned *access token*, and if you want to protect user account, you should be careful and choose secure storage like `Keychain`.

Remember, `UserDefaults` is just simple XML file and anybody with access to device can read it.

[This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/147308/secure-ios-user-data-keychain-touch-id) is good tutorial about secure iOS User Data

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are asking how to transfer data between different view controllers within a tab bar controller.  This is how I've done it:

Define the tab bar class and variable to hold the data:

```
class ItemTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    var allTags: [TagData] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("ItemTabBarController.viewDidLoad")
    }
}
```

Make sure that the custom class property for the tab bar in the storyboard is "ItemTabBarController"

In each view controller that wants to set a value in the tab bar:

```
func configureItemTabBarController() {
        let itemTabBarController = self.tabBarController  as! ItemTabBarController
        self.viewModel.allTags = viewModel.configureAllTags()
        itemTabBarController.allTags = self.viewModel.allTags
    }
```