# Passing data between UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

How could I pass data from **first** TabBarVC to **second**?

---

I have a `UILabel` with some string which update every time when I choose another cell in the `UITableView`. 
But for example I have only `String` var and `UILabel` with it.

```
var myString: String = NSLocalizedString("MyString1", comment: "")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label1.text = myString
}
```

And I try to make a function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if (segue.identifier == "TbVC1toTbVC2") {
      if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? TbVC2 {
           nextViewController.transferMyString = myString
      }
   }
}
```

---

In the TbVC2 I write something like this:

```
 var transferMyString: String = NSLocalizedString("WrongString", comment: "")

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     label2.text = transferMyString
 }
```

But after it still not show transferred data in **second** Tab Bar ViewController.

Comment: Nice solution is to create singleton class and share data with it

Comment: This case can be solved with delegate back or call straight to the `self.tabBarController` and ask it to update the rest of its child view controllers via `tabbarVC.viewControllers`, singleton is eh...always the last solution if there's no way else

Comment: Here’s one way to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/27619420/1630618

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my opinion better passing data is implemented in tabbarcontroller class.

[image]

for example:

```
import UIKit

class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    var firstVC = FirstVC()
    var secondVC = SecondVC()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self

        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        // Create Tab one
        firstVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstVC") as! FirstVC
        let tabOneBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Tab 1", image: UIImage(named: "defaultImage.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "selectedImage.png"))

        firstVC.tabBarItem = tabOneBarItem


        // Create Tab two
        secondVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! SecondVC
        let tabTwoBarItem2 = UITabBarItem(title: "Tab 2", image: UIImage(named: "defaultImage2.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "selectedImage2.png"))

        secondVC.tabBarItem = tabTwoBarItem2


        self.viewControllers = [firstVC, secondVC]
    }
}

// MARK: - Delegate
extension TabBarViewController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if let secondVC = viewController as? SecondVC {
            secondVC.secondLabel.text = firstVC.firstLabel.text
        }
    }
}
```

firstVC:

```
import UIKit

class FirstVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!

    var stringText = "this is from firstVC"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        firstLabel.text = stringText
    }
}
```

secondVC:

```
import UIKit

class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!
    var stringText = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        secondLabel.text = stringText
    }
}
```